# Building query to filter for date using QGIS

Tags: qgis, filter, date

I am using QGIS.

I want to filter for all datapoints that were taken over a specific period: 01/01/2015 to 31/12/2015. If I use the 'filter features using form' I can manage this, however I wanted to do it in the Query Builder.

This is the Specific Filter Expression I use:

```
"Date">'01/01/2015' AND "Date"<'31/12/2015'
```

(As "Date" is the field column in my data sheet)

When I submit this however, in addition to the second filter I am applying ("Label", and I have no issue with this filter), I find that the date filter has been completely disregarded, and my data is only filtered by "Label".

How do I filter for a specific date duration?

Comment: You could start by using ISO 8601 date representation - YYYY-MM-DD ([ob xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1179/)). This assumes that the Date column is an actual date type. Otherwise it's just a string comparison, and the results are randomized by failure to use ISO 8601.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [@Vince already mentioned](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/407289/building-query-to-filter-for-date/407292#comment662615_407289), this is not a [`date`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) but a `string`. You need to convert it to a date first, then you can do the comparison. You can use [`to_date()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#expression-function-date-and-time-to-date) function in field calculator like:

```
to_date('01/01/2015','dd/MM/yyyy')
```

so your expression would look something like:

```
"Date">to_date('01/01/2015','dd/MM/yyyy') AND "Date"<to_date('31/12/2015','dd/MM/yyyy')
```

Note that this of course also will only work if your `Date` field is actually a `date` and not just another `string`. If it is a string as well, you need to convert it to a date first in the same way. E.g.

```
to_date("Date",'dd/MM/yyyy')>to_date('01/01/2015','dd/MM/yyyy') AND to_date("Date",'dd/MM/yyyy')<to_date('31/12/2015','dd/MM/yyyy')
```